# Why is code looping back to the main menu after the user chooses an option 1 in subMenu1?

Tags: loops, methods

I'm creating a CD collection program and for now, I'm just allowing the user to choose from a list of options from menus I've created. I'm wondering why the program loops back to the Main Menu after the user had chosen an option from a subMenu. For example, if the user chooses to enter sub Menu 1, and choose the first option, it displays the correct method but for some reason loops back to the Main Menu. Can someone help me figure out why?  (to make it shorter, I've removed the imports here, but in my actual code they're there.

//code

```
public class Driver1 {
    public static int answer, mainMenuChoice, subMenuChoice;
    public static String back, file;
    static boolean  back1;
    static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    public static void displayMainMenu (BufferedReader stdIn) throws IOException{
        do {
            back1=false;
            System.out.println ("----------  MAIN MENU  -----------");
            System.out.println ("1) Accessing your list of CDs");
            System.out.println ("2) Accessing within a particular CD");
            System.out.println ("3) Exit");
            System.out.println ("----------------------------------");
            System.out.print ("\n\nPlease enter your choice:  ");

            answer = Integer.parseInt (stdIn.readLine ());

            if (answer==1) 
                displaySubMenu(1,stdIn);

            else if (answer==2)
                displaySubMenu(2,stdIn);

            else if(answer==3)
                System.exit(0);
            else {
                while (!(answer==1|| answer==2|| answer==3)) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please only input numbers 1 to 3: ");
                    answer = Integer.parseInt (stdIn.readLine ());
                }
            }
        }while(back1=true); 



    }

    public static int displaySubMenu (int subMenuNum, BufferedReader stdIn) throws IOException{
        if (subMenuNum == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("\n---------  SUB-MENU #1  ----------");
            System.out.println ("1) Display all of your CDs"); // Just the CD titles, numbered in order
            System.out.println ("2) Display info on a particular CD"); // Just the CD titles, numbered in order
            System.out.println ("3) Add a CD"); // Adds a CD by reading from input file
            System.out.println ("4) Remove a CD");
            System.out.println ("5) Copy a CD");
            System.out.println ("6) Create a sub-CD");
            System.out.println ("7) List songs in common between two CDs");
            System.out.println ("8) Return back to main menu.");
            System.out.println ("----------------------------------");
            System.out.println ("\n\nPlease enter your choice:  ");

            answer = Integer.parseInt (stdIn.readLine ());

            if (answer==1) 
                subMenu1(1,stdIn);
            else if (answer==2)
                subMenu1(2,stdIn);
            else if (answer==8) {
                back1=true;
                displayMainMenu(stdIn);
            }

        }
        else if (subMenuNum == 2) {
            System.out.println ("\n---------  SUB-MENU #2  ----------");
            System.out.println ("1) Display all songs (in the last sorted order) ");
            System.out.println ("2) Display info on a particular song ");
            System.out.println ("3) Add song");
            System.out.println ("4) Remove Song (4 options)");
            System.out.println ("5) Sort songs (3 options)");
            System.out.println ("6) Return back to main menu");
            System.out.println ("----------------------------------");
        }
        else if (subMenuNum == 3) {
            //code here 
        }

        else
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please input a number from 1-3");
return answer;
    }
    public static int subMenu1 (int subMenuNum, BufferedReader stdIn) throws IOException{
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


        if (subMenuNum == 1) {
            System.out.println("subMenuNum=1");     
        }

        else if (subMenuNum==2)
            System.out.println("subMenuNum=2");

        else if (subMenuNum==8) {
            back1=true;
            displayMainMenu(stdIn);
        }


        return subMenuNum;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        displayMainMenu(stdIn);



    }
}
```

Comment: You should try as best as possible to distill your code into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to make it easier for others to focus on solving the core issue at hand.

Comment: Sorry about that! To be honest I thought the whole code needed to be posted as it shows all the methods.